# Type 'Promise<any>' is not assignable to type 'CanReturnChainable' in Cypress

Tags: typescript, cypress

I have just upgraded Cypress version to `4.9.0` from `4.8.0` and got:

[image]

Example of test:

```
it('should have the right initial login state', () => {
  cy.fixture('loginInitialState').then(initialState => {
    cy.wait(100);
    cy.window().should('have.property', 'store');
    cy.checkReduxState('login', 'initial', initialState);
  });

  cy.pause();
});
```

and I was thinking that following adding type will help:

```
it('should have the right initial login state', () => {
  cy.fixture('loginInitialState').then(initialState => {
    cy.wait(100);
    cy.window().should('have.property', 'store');
    <any>cy.checkReduxState('login', 'initial', initialState);
  });

  cy.pause();
});
```

But it did not help, any idea? I use TypeScript.

Comment: It could have something to do with https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/435

Comment: Maybe it needs `cy.wrap()`.

Comment: I've opened https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/7807

Comment: @StevenVachon All I can do now is to add thumb up. Thanks for the issue! ;-)